# issues with transforming dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling with figuring out how to transform a table from from one layout to another:

```
Table1
DEP_NO  POSITION_CATEGORY   NAME
177     CLERICAL            BETTY SMITH
177     MANAGER             GRAHAM BROWN
177     EXECUTIVE           DAVID GREEN
200     CLERICAL            BETSY ROSS
200     MANAGER             GEORGE EAST
200     EXECUTIVE           MORRIS SMITH
300     CLERICAL            PHIL ORANGE
300     MANAGER             HAL SARTRE
300     EXECUTIVE           MARISOL BERN
400     CLERICAL            LISA HEAD
400     MANAGER             LINDA TELLER
400     EXECUTIVE           NICE GUY

Table2
DEP_NO  CLERICAL        MANAGER          EXECUTIVE
177     BETTY SMITH     GRAHAM BROWN     DAVID GREEN
200     BETSY ROSS      GEORGE EAST      MORRIS SMITH
300     PHIL ORANGE     HAL SARTRE       MARISOL BERN
400     LISA HEAD       LINDA TELLER     NICE GUY
```

As you can see contents of `tables1` column two are column names in `table2`,
and the names in `table1` become the contents in `table2`

My pandas knowledge is a bit rudimentary, and I cant figure out what the easiest way to get the transform accomplished is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go from Table 1 to Table 2, you can use pivot. Specifically, you want to use DEP_NO as the idenx, because it's defining your row labels. Columns should be "POSITION_CATEGORY" because that is the column holding your column names. Assuming your data frame is stored in `df`:

```
df.pivot(index="DEP_NO", columns="POSITION_CATEGORY")
```

To go from Table 2 to Table 1 you can use melt. By default, melt creates a two column data frame where each entry in your original data frame gets its own row. The first column indicates which column in the original data frame that row came from and the second column indicates what the value was. In this case, you want to keep track of which DEP_NO was associated with which value. You can tell pandas not to melt the DEP_NO column by using the id_vars keyword argument as shown below. All of the other column names are the values you want to label "POSITION_CATEGORY", so you can tell pandas to give that name to the variable column with the var_name keyword argument. Lastly, all of the values from your original data frame are names, so you can label that column accordingly with the "value_name" keyword argument:

```
df.melt(id_vars=["DEP_NO"], var_name="POSITION_CATEGORY", value_name="NAME")
```

Comment: This is great! The extra detail you provided helped me understand  how to use it effectively.

Answer (score 0):

You just need `pivot` .

```
df.pivot(*df.columns)
Out[280]: 
POSITION_CATEGORY     CLERICAL     EXECUTIVE       MANAGER
DEP_NO                                                    
177                BETTY SMITH   DAVID GREEN  GRAHAM BROWN
200                 BETSY ROSS  MORRIS SMITH   GEORGE EAST
300                PHIL ORANGE  MARISOL BERN    HAL SARTRE
400                  LISA HEAD      NICE GUY  LINDA TELLER
```